# Jmeter is not running the HttpSamplerProxy

Tags: java, jmeter

I am running this with jmeter core and jmeter http both at version 5.3. I am confused to why the sampler will not fire off. I am new to using jmeter in this fashion and am not quite sure how this all works. When the code is ran i end up with no request data in the jtl file.

```
        //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(System.getenv("JMETER_HOME") + "/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        // JMeter Test Plan, basic all u JOrphan HashTree
        HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

        // HTTP Sampler
        HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
        httpSampler.setDomain("example.com");
        httpSampler.setPort(80);
        httpSampler.setPath("/");
        httpSampler.setMethod("GET");

        // Loop Controller
        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setLoops(1);
        loopController.addTestElement(httpSampler);
        loopController.setFirst(true);
        loopController.initialize();

        // Thread Group
        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);

        // Test Plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");

        // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
        testPlanTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
        testPlanTree.add("loopController", loopController);
        testPlanTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
        testPlanTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);

        // Run Test Plan
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, this code:

```
testPlanTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
testPlanTree.add("loopController", loopController);
testPlanTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
testPlanTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);
```

needs to be replaced by

```
testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
threadGroupHashTree.add(httpSampler);
```

I also fail to see where you're saving the results into the .jtl, you need to add [ResultCollector](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/ResultCollector.html) like this:

```
Summariser summer = null;
String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
    summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
}


String logFile = "/path/to/result.jtl";
ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
logger.setFilename(logFile);
testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
```

before `jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);` line

In general creating JMeter tests using API is not very supported and there is no any guarantee that the code will work after next JMeter release so I would rather rely on 3rd-party options like [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) or [jmeter-java-dsl](https://github.com/abstracta/jmeter-java-dsl)

However if for some reason you want to continue you can get some examples in [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article and in [jmeter-from-code repo](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/demo/JMeterFromScratch.java)